# How to group by 2 columns with counts in Panda?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, count

This is the Table:

| NAME: | DATE: |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 2022-10-04 |
| Apple | 2022-10-04 |
| Apple | 2022-10-04 |
| Orange | 2022-10-04 |
| Apple | 2022-10-06 |
| Apple | 2022-10-06 |
| Apple | 2022-10-06 |

I would like to group by name & date, and also add a column called 'Counts'.

OUTCOME that I wanna look like:

| NAME: | DATE: | COUNTS: |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 2022-10-04 | 3 |
| Orange | 2022-10-04 | 1 |
| Apple | 2022-10-06 | 3 |

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it:

```
df.groupby(['NAME', 'DATE']).DATE.agg('count').to_frame('COUNTS').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
     NAME        DATE  COUNTS
0   apple  2022-10-04       3
1   apple  2022-10-06       3
2  orange  2022-10-04       1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
df.value_counts(['NAME', 'DATE']).rename('COUNTS').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
     NAME        DATE  COUNTS
0   Apple  2022-10-04       3
1   Apple  2022-10-06       3
2  Orange  2022-10-04       1
```